# Request object has no attribute "accepted_renderer"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What happens if this problem occurs? 
Request object has no attribute "accepted_renderer"

These messages were in my log.

1. There was error encountered while processing this event.
2. Discarded invalid value for parameter 'timestamp' Expand

base viewset class:

```
class BaseViewSet(LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(BaseViewSet, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, 
                            SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
            permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
            renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer, 
                         AdminRenderer,)

            def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                user = request.user.baseuser
                user.last_visit = datetime.datetime.now()
                user.save()
                super(LoggingMixin, self).initial(request, *args,**kwargs)
```

my api :

```
api_v1_router.register(prefix=r'notify', viewset=NotificationViewSet, base_name='notify')
```

my viewset :

```
class NotificationViewSet(BaseViewSet):
queryset = Notification.objects.all()
serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(send_to_id=request.user.id, seen=False).order_by('-created_date')

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

my setting.py :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
],
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
    'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
),
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.AdminRenderer',
),
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':'apps.common.helpers.pagination.CustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 12}
```

traceback:

```
    AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'
  File "rest_framework/request.py", line 382, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(self._request, attr)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
    response = super(BaseLoggingMixin, self).handle_exception(exc)
  File "rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "rest_framework/views.py", line 457, in raise_uncaught_exception
    renderer_format = getattr(request.accepted_renderer, 'format')
  File "rest_framework/request.py", line 384, in __getattribute__
    six.reraise(info[0], info[1], info[2].tb_next)
  File "django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner
i added traceback to question

Comment: What is `BaseViewSet`? Add that code here please.

Comment: @rtindru 
ok I added in question....

Comment: Which version of DRF and Django are you using?

Comment: @rtindru
Django==1.11.3
djangorestframework==3.6.3
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0

Comment: Add code for `LoggingMixin` as well pls; ensure that you have all required code for debugging while posting your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in the `super` call within your override of `def initial`. You need to call the super method on the `BaseViewSet` and not on `LoggingMixin`.

Change your super line as follows:

`super(BaseViewSet, self).initial(request, *args,**kwargs)`

This will ensure that all respective `super` calls are carried out; and will ensure that the `APIView.initial` call is made; which then setst he `accept_renderer` attribute as follows:

The `def initial` method in the APIView (which is used internally by ModelViewSet) is the one that sets the `accepted_renderer` attribute on the `Request` object. Here's the source code:

```
   def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Runs anything that needs to occur prior to calling the method handler.
        """
        self.format_kwarg = self.get_format_suffix(**kwargs)

        # Perform content negotiation and store the accepted info on the request
        neg = self.perform_content_negotiation(request)
        request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg

        # Determine the API version, if versioning is in use.
        version, scheme = self.determine_version(request, *args, **kwargs)
        request.version, request.versioning_scheme = version, scheme

        # Ensure that the incoming request is permitted
        self.perform_authentication(request)
        self.check_permissions(request)
        self.check_throttles(request)
```

**Caveat**

The answer changes if you have defined a `def initial` inside `LoggingMixin`. If you have; I'd like to understand why; since the super call to `ModelViewset.initial` needs to be satisfied somehow.

Comment: The initial function inside LoggingMixin is not set by the user, it's defined in the drf_tracking library

Answer (score 6):

In my case this was https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6300 and missing `pyyaml`