# how overwrite Response class in django rest framework ( DRF )?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, response, django-generic-views

I want to overwrite `Response` class of django rest framework so that response back responsive dictionary contain three parameter `message`, `status` and `data`

Hello dears all

I try to change `Response Class` in `DRF` to pass two extra parameter ( message, status ) plus data provide by DRF serializer. `message` pass the message like `Done`, `User Created` or etc and `status` pass the message like `fail` or `success` or etc message and this message useful for reserve special code between frontend and backend.

I want to if don't set this parameter return empty character or null result back to client side

for example in success mode:

```
{
    'data': {
        'value_one': 'some data',
        'value_two': 'some data',
        'value_three': [
                'value', 'value', 'value'
            ],
        },
    }
    'message': 'Done',
    'status': 'success',
}
```

and in failure mode:

```
{
    'data': ['any error message raise by serializer',]
    'message': 'Create User Failed',
    'status': 'failure',
}
```

I search about my question and found this solution:

if i inheritance `DRF Response Class` in my class and overwrite `__init__` method and get message, data and status in this method and call **init** of parent with own data structure and use this responsive class in my functionality like this implement:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class Response(Response):

    def __init__(self, data=None, message=None, data_status=None, status=None,
                template_name=None, headers=None,
                exception=False, content_type=None):

        data_content = {
            'status': data_status,
            'data': data,
            'message': message,
        }
        super(Response, self).__init__(
            data=data_content,
            status=status,
            template_name=template_name,
            headers=headers,
            exception=exception,
            content_type=content_type
        )
```

in success mode call:

```
return Response(data=serializer.data, message='Done', data_status='success', status=200)
```

in failure mode call:

```
return Response(data=serializer.errors, message='Create User Failed', data_status='failure', status=400)
```

and use own Response class in all views class
we had `problem` in this solution: if we use `GenericViews Class` must be overwrite all http methods we used in view's logic and call own class and this is **DRY!!**

---

and other solution i found. in serialized layer, we have abstract method `def to_representation(self, instance):` in `Serializer` class and implement in other class like `ModelSerializer` class inheritance `Serializer` and if we overwrite this method in our serializer class and re fetch data before send to view layer, implement like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OurSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

....

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(serializers.ModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        result = OrderedDict()
        result['data'] = data
        result['message'] = 'Done'
        result['status'] = 'sucssed'
        return result
```

this solution solve above problem but we have two problem again

one: if we use nested serializer and we had overwrite this function in serializer class return bad data like:

```
{
    'data': {
        'value_one': 'some data',
        'value_two': 'some data',
        'value_three': {
            'data': [
                'value', 'value', 'value'
            ],
            'message': 'Done',
            'status': 'sucssed',
        },
    }
    'message': 'Done',
    'status': 'sucssed',
}
```

and `message` and `status` repeated and structure not pretty for client

and two: we cant handle exception in this mode and just way to handle exception just with middleware class like this [DRF Exception Handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) and this isn't useful way, we can't handle any type of error occurs in view and generate comfortable separate `message` and `status`.

IF there's another good solution to this question, please guide me.

thanks :)

Comment: what about writing custom middleware? usually it is a good place to make things happen with requests/responses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To resolve this, best practice (that DRF has proposed) is to use 'renderer' classes. A renderer manipulates and returns structured response.

Django uses renderers like [Template Renderer](http://google.com) and DRF benefits this feature and provides [API Renderers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/).

To do so, you could provide such this renderer in a package (e.g. `app_name.renderers.ApiRenderer`):

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer
from rest_framework.utils import json


class ApiRenderer(BaseRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        response_dict = {
            'status': 'failure',
            'data': {},
            'message': '',
        }
        if data.get('data'):
            response_dict['data'] = data.get('data')
        if data.get('status'):
            response_dict['status'] = data.get('status')
        if data.get('message'):
            response_dict['message'] = data.get('message')
        data = response_dict
        return json.dumps(data)
```

And then in your settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'app_name.renderers.ApiRenderer',
    ),
    ...
}
```

By this action all views that extend DRF generic views will use renderer. If you needed to override setting you can use `renderer_classes` attribute for generic view classes and `@renderer_classes` decorator for api view functions.

A comprehensive renderer class to override is available at `<virtualenv_dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py`.

Comment: How should I pass ```status``` and ```message``` in my generic views which I don't want to override? In this case the ```status``` and ```message``` would be always ```failure``` and ```''``` because the generic ones do not pass ```status``` and ```message``` to ```data``` of ```Response``` by default.

Comment: @SirbitoX did you resolve your issue above? I have the same question.

Comment: @Maps You have 2 options for status. 1- set default (failure or succes) 2- leave empty if not passed. It's completely up to you to choose.

Comment: this returned this error for me  `'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'`

Comment: @AhmedWagdi check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073864/request-object-has-no-attribute-accepted-renderer and https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6300

Comment: unable to deal with `accepted_renderer` error.

Answer (score 12):

This would be more a more robust solution, as it can be used with **Generic Views** hassle free.

In case of Generic views, the data argument we receive in the render() method is sent **automatically** by the generic view itself (if not overriding the methods, which will be against DRY), so we cannot handle it, as it does in the accepted answer.

Also, the checks in render() can be easily altered as per the needs (Eg., handling no-2XX status codes in this solution).

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer


class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        response = {
          "status": "success",
          "code": status_code,
          "data": data,
          "message": None
        }

        if not str(status_code).startswith('2'):
            response["status"] = "error"
            response["data"] = None
            try:
                response["message"] = data["detail"]
            except KeyError:
                response["data"] = data

        return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

Comment: how to pass `message` dynamic ?

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh get_renderer_context is a method which you can override in which you can pass message, which can then be retrieved from the renderer_context of render method. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43903251/9851115

Answer (score 5):

**Just an addition**: I prefer to inherit from `JSONRenderer`. That way you get the nice formatting and indentation out of the box

```
    from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
    
    class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):
          
          def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
              response = {
                 'error': False,
                 'message': 'Success',
                 'data': data
              }

              return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

Then in your views:

```
    from rest_framework.renderers import BrowsableAPIRenderer
    from api.renderers import CustomRenderer

    class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
          renderer_classes = [CustomRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer]
          
          ...
```

When used with the `BrowsableAPIRenderer` as shown above, you get your nicely formatted custom response rendered in DRF's Browsable API

Comment: how should i pass `message` dynamic ? 
`Response({products:products}, status=status.500, message='custom_message')`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to write custom Response middleware:

```
class ResponseCustomMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResponseCustomMiddleware, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):

        if not response.is_rendered and isinstance(response, Response):
            if isinstance(response.data, dict):
                message = response.data.get('message', 'Some error occurred')
                if 'data' not in response.data:
                    response.data = {'data': response.data}
                response.data.setdefault('message', message)
                # you can add you logic for checking in status code is 2** or 4**.
                data_status = 'unknown'
                if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                    data_status = 'success'
                elif response.status_code // 100 == 4:
                    data_status = 'failure'
                response.data.setdefault('data_status', data_status)
        return response
```

Add middleware in settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # you all middleware here,
    'common.middleware.ResponseCustomMiddleware',
]
```

So you can return `Response` like this:

```
data = {'var1': 1, 'var2': 2}
return Response({'data': data, 'message': 'This is my message'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Response will be like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "var1": 1,
        "var2": 2
    }
  ],
  "message": "This is my message",
  "data_status": "success"
}
```

Comment: can you update your answer `MiddlewareMixin` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve the problem. I hope it helps

```py
    def custom_response(data, code=None, message=None):
      if not code and not message:
        code = SUCCESSFUL_CODE
        message = SUCCESSFUL_MESSAGE
      return Response(OrderedDict([
        ('code', code),
        ('message', message),
        ('results', data)
    ]))
```

Now in your views function. You can custom the response however you want pretty easy `return custom_response(data=..,message=...,code=...)`